# Cucumber BeforeAll hook is not being executed

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber, playwright, cucumberjs

I am using Cucumber with Playwright. I need to launch the Chromium browser via Playwright in BeforeAll hook, and pass the browser instance to page objects so that they can control the browser. 
Here is the project structure:

```
project_folder:
 |_ _build // <= compiled files
 |_ configs
 |_ node_module
 |_ src
   |_ features
   |_ page_objects
   |_ step_definitions
   |_ utils
 |_ hooks.ts
 |_ package.json
 |_ tsconfig.json
```

hooks.ts:

```
let browserPage: Page;
let pages: PageFactory;

BeforeAll({timeout: 120000}, async function (){
  const usersRoles = ['admin', 'publisher', 'advertiser', 'agency'];
  for (const user of usersRoles) {
    await saveLoginSession(user as User);
  }
  browserPage = await createBrowserPage('chrome', {headless: false});
  pages = new PageFactory(browserPage);
});

Before({tags: '@skipAuth'}, async function () {
  const browserName = process.env.BROWSER as 'chrome' | 'firefox' | 'webkit' || 'chrome';
  browserPage = await createBrowserPage(browserName, {headless: false});
})

After(async function ({ pickle, result}) {
  if (result!.status === Status.FAILED) {
    await takeScreenshot.call(this, pickle, browserPage);
  }
});

AfterAll(async function () {
  await browserPage.close();
})

export {browserPage, pages};
```

pageFactory.ts:

```
export class PageFactory {
    constructor(page: Page) {
        this['Cognito page'] = new CognitoPage(page);
        this['Dashboard page'] = new DashboardPage(page);
        this['Home page'] = new LandingPage(page);
        this['Login page'] = new LoginPage(page);
        this['Campaign wizard'] = new CampaignWizard(page)
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM", "ES2019"],
    "outDir": "_build",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": false
  },
  "include": ["configs", "src", "hooks.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

cucumber.cjs:

```
module.exports = {
  default: {
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: 'async-await'
    },
    paths: [
      'src/features/'
    ],
    dryRun: false,
    require: [
      '_build/src/step_definitions/**/*.js', // <= compiled files
      '_build/hooks.js' // <= compiled files
    ],
    requireModule: [
      'ts-node/register'
    ],
    format: [
      'json:test-results/json-report.json',
      'progress'
    ],
    parallel: process.env.CI ? 10 : 1
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "core-regression-bdd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "node _build/src/utils/report/reportInit.js",
    "test": "cucumber-js --config=configs/cucumber.cjs || true",
    "posttest": "node _build/src/utils/report/reporter.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^9.5.1",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.38.0",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

When I run tests I encounter that the browser is not initialized (in the BeforeAll hook) and I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locator')
    at new DashboardPage (C:\Users\Jasurbek\Documents\Projects\core-regression-bdd\_build\src\page_objects\DashboardPage.js:10:30)
    at new PageFactory (C:\Users\Jasurbek\Documents\Projects\core-regression-bdd\_build\src\page_objects\pageFactory.js:8:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jasurbek\Documents\Projects\core-regression-bdd\_build\src\step_definitions\campaignWizard.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)       
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\Jasurbek\
Documents\Projects\core-regression-bdd\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)  
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)        
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
```

saveSession.ts:

```
const { credentials: {currentEnv} } = secrets;

export async function saveLoginSession(coreUser: User) {
  const page: Page = await createBrowserPage('chrome', {headless: false});

  await authenticateInCognito(
    secrets.credentials.cognito[currentEnv].username,
    secrets.credentials.cognito[currentEnv].password,
    page
  );
  await authenticateInCore(
    secrets.credentials.core[`${coreUser.toLowerCase()}`].username,
    secrets.credentials.core[`${coreUser.toLowerCase()}`].password,
    page
  );

  await page.context().storageState({ path: `${path.resolve('session_data')}/${currentEnv}.${coreUser}.state.json`});
  await page.context().clearCookies();
  await page.close();
  console.info(` Successfully saved the session | ${coreUser}.state.json`);
}
```

creatBrowserPage.ts:

```
import {Browser, chromium, firefox, webkit, LaunchOptions, Page} from "@playwright/test";
const browsers = {
  chrome: chromium,
  firefox,
  webkit
}
export let browserInfo: { type?: string; version?: string } = {};

export async function createBrowserPage(browserName: 'chrome' | 'firefox' | 'webkit' = 'chrome', launchOptions?: LaunchOptions) {
  const browser: Browser = process.env.browser
    ? await browsers[process.env.browser].launch(launchOptions)
    : await browsers[browserName].launch(launchOptions);
  const page: Page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewportSize({width: 1440, height: 780});
  browserInfo['type'] = browser.browserType.toString()
  browserInfo['version'] = browser.version.toString()
  return page;
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
export const invokeBrowser = () => {
  const browserType=process.env.npm_config_BROWSER || process.env.PWG_ENV_BDD_BROWSER || 'chrome';
  console.log(browserType);
    
  // const browserType ='chrome';
  switch (browserType) {
    case 'chrome':
      return chromium.launch(options);
    case 'firefox':
      return firefox.launch(options);
    case 'webkit':
      return webkit.launch(options);
    default:
      throw new Error('Please set the proper browser');
  }
};
```

Call in `BeforeAll`:

```
BeforeAll(async function() {
  rpApiPage = new ReportPortalPage();
  console.log('BeforeAll Start>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ');
  const tags: any = Constants.getRpTags();
    
  // browser = `enter code here`await chromium.launch({ headless:false });
  getEnv();
  browser = await invokeBrowser();
});
```